# An interesting problem from circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Consider this situation:
Two individuals are seating side by side on a Merry-go-Round  moving with angular velocity $\omega$) seats they are just seating next to one another. Now the person A is staring at the person B for the whole journey. So as both of them are moving, he doesn't have to move he's head anywhere in order to see person B.

But as we know in case of a rod hinged on one side and is rotated around with some angular velocity $\omega$ (see diagram below), we know that from M's point of view N is rotating around it with angular velocity $\omega$. So if there's a person at M he will have to rotate his head around with angular velocity $\omega$ in order to see N moving around him/her.

So both cases are similar but one says that you need not turn your head in order to see the other person. But one says you will have to do so!

So my question is why is it so?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any reason why M has to move his/her neck. The two cases are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I wonder why in case 2 you didn't just stick with the merry-go-round and ask what person B has to do to look at person A.  I have a theory, though, that suggests you've switched something more important between the two cases.  Let me explain.

The important thing to realize about case 1 is that you've implicitly assumed person A is also rotating (relative to the ground, say) with angular velocity $\omega$.  This may be a little confusing, because person A is also moving in a circle — but in addition to that circular motion she's also rotating.  You could imagine a situation in which person A is constantly staring (say) North, even as she goes around in a circle, but that's not what happens on a merry-go-round because the two ropes of the swing are fixed.  Instead, you get rotation along with the circular motion.  And so, even though person B is also going in a circle with angular velocity $\omega$, person A doesn't have to compensate for that motion to look at person B because her head is already rotating at the angular velocity.

It seems that you've assumed otherwise for case 2.  Specifically, you seem to have assumed that M is *not* rotating with angular velocity $\omega$, but is only going in a circle with angular velocity $\omega$.  This different scenario gives you a different answer — which shouldn't be a surprise.

The common theme here — as in most problems with angular velocity — is that you always need to remember where you're measuring motion from, or the axis *relative to which* rotation is being measured.  For example, in case 1, person A is moving *relative to the axis of the merry-go-round* with angular velocity $\omega$ ***and*** is rotating *relative to her own center of mass* with angular velocity.  In case 2, it appears that you assumed person M is only rotating relative to the axis, but not relative to his own center of mass.